# why does python's win32gui.SendMessageTimeout fail and delete most of my Environment Variables?

Tags: python, bash, windows-7, operating-system, environment-variables

This code snippet is very standard: (you'll find it on many sites)

```
rc, dwReturnValue = win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, "Environment", win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000 )
```

On one machine it deletes MOST, but not all, environment variables: 
these variables get deleted :  (and others)

```
Path
PYTHONPATH
VS100COMNTOOLS
windir
XEDK
```

When I say deleted, what I mean is that the originating shell has an intact environment, but all subsequent environment shells do NOT have these environment variables, which to say the least, is 'somewhat' bothersome.

I have tried this code on at least 4 other machines, and there are no problems. The code works perfectly.

On the one problematic machine, a log off/log on seems to solve the problem, (and reinstate the missing env vars)

I have researched a lot on the almighty google and found nothing on errors with the method win32gui.SendMessageTimeout
Only found threads on people not invoking the method correctly. (perhaps this thread will join those ranks! :) )

I have been running spy++ (I'm a spy++ noob) and can see that the WM_SETTINGCHANGE Message is being received correctly by a few different windows on the problematic machine.

```
print str(rc),"<- return code"
print str(dwReturnValue), "<- return value"
```

yields

```
1 <- return code
0 <- return value
```

Here is my setup:

- OS - Windows 7
- python 2.7.1
- cywin 19.5

process is a 
batch file (install.bat) (this sets %CYGWIN_ROOT%)

```
(...)
:BASH_INSTALL_SCRIPT
::write paths file that will be used to modify system paths
set PATH=%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
::call bash install sequence
"%BASH_EXE%" install.sh %CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin %*
```

install.sh snippet:

```
function setCygwinPath {
# Install script of Cygwin set CYGWIN_ROOT in current env variables.
setEnvVar "CYGWIN_PATH" $CYGWIN_ROOT
}

function setEnvVar {
"$PythonRoot/python.exe" ../utils/${project}/setEnvVar.py $1 $2
(...)    }
```

setEnvVar.py

```
from install.installUtils import *
setUserEnvVar( sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

installUtils.py

```
def setUserEnvVar( varName, content, type=wreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, override=0 ):
    """ Set the specified environment variable """
    setEnvVarAndBroadcast( wreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, getUserEnvKey(), varName, content, type, override )

def setEnvVarAndBroadcast( domain, regKey, varName, content, type=wreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, override=0 ):
    """ Set an environment variable and broadcast to opened application """
    if override == 0 :
        # If the variable exist reuse its current type
        varInfo = getEnvVarEx( domain, regKey, varName )
        if varInfo[0] <> "" :
            type = varInfo[1]

    key = wreg.OpenKey(domain, regKey, 0, wreg.KEY_WRITE )    
    wreg.SetValueEx( key, varName, 0, type, content)
    wreg.CloseKey( key )

    HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002

    rc, dwReturnValue = win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, "Environment", win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000 )
```

I have isolated absolutely that the call win32gui.SendMessageTimeout is what disrupts the machine's environment variables.

This code was previously working on this machine, until a week ago (no idea what has changed; I would say nothing,

questions: 
This seems like a bit of an exploit...... am i wrong?
I'm not really sure what to investigate anymore, so I would welcome a solution (obviously) but even an idea for investigation would be welcome. I have only win32gui.pyd (no sources) on the machine in question.

The machine goes from having 73 Environment Variables to 46 ( c:> set ). A lot of them are user installed applications, but some are System (like PATH, windir).